# Is there a way to insert an image into a chart in xlsxwriter?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

In Excel it's possible to insert [images into charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW2Nj.png) for fun and profit.

I'd like to replicate that in xlsxwriter, but can't figure out how to do it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html) on its Chart class does not contain the word "image", I would say it can't be done with xlsxwriter.

Comment: Correct. Inserting images, or objects, into Charts isn't supported in XlsxWriter. I am the author.